# Optional Property but Required Input

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor-pages

In my particular case, I am importing data from a legacy application.  In the new application, I have a model's property (`GradYear`) that did not exist in the legacy application.  I need to import the data from the legacy database to the new database for historical purposes.  However, in the new application `GradYear` is `required`.

Using EF Core and Razor Pages, is there a way to make `GradYear` required at the rendered input textbox level but optional in the db schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think in this possible solution:

1. Use a 2 different viewmodels, one for importing from legacy with non required field, other for internal new application use with required attribute, you just need to get sure in the non required viewmodel that you assign a default value when mapping to the DBContext entity.

Another way (not tested) is decorate your property as required but override OnModelCreating like this :

```
public class YourAppContext : DbContext
{
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
      ...
      modelBuilder.Entity<YourDbContextEntity>.Property(p => p.GradYear).IsOptional();
      ...
   }

}
```

Comment: The 2 different viewmodels idea worked for me.  However, declaring the property optional with `int?` does not allow for an `IsOptional();` extension method.